# Angular client needs Access Token for Web API

Tags: angular, rest, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a Web API secured by OWIN that requires the user to be authenticated using Azure Active Directory. I’m able to make requests via Postman with the access token I obtained using the Microsoft Authorization URL.

From my Angular client (also secured by Azure AD), however, I cannot get the access token for the Web API without getting redirected to the API. Is there any way for the client app (which has a different client id than the Server API) to retrieve the access token it needs to use in the Authorization header of API requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have registred two applications in your Azure Active Directory (your UI and your API). You need to **grant the UI access on behalf of the current** User for the **API**. You login the user using the registred UI application ID and finally retrieve an access token for the API.

Here the pseudo code for the `ng2-adal` component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthconfigService {

  constructor() { }

  public get adalConfig(): any {
    return {
      tenant: 'yourTenant.onmicrosoft.com',
      clientId: 'UI AppId (GUID)',
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/'
    };
  }

  public get apiKey(): string
  {
    return "API AppId (GUID)";
  }

}
```

Then in your app.component.ts:

```
this.adalService.init(this.authconfigService.adalConfig);
this.adalService.login();

this.adalService.acquireToken(this.authconfigService.apiKey).subscribe(
      (data) => {
.....});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing this, but for some reason this works (using the UI AppId):


`this.adalService.acquireToken(this.authconfigService.adalConfig.clientId).subscribe(
      (data) => {
.....});`

But this (using the API AppId) does not:

`this.adalService.acquireToken(this.authconfigService.apiKey).subscribe(
      (data) => {
.....});`


In adal.js, if (resource !== this.config.clientId), it calls renewToken, but goes into a recursive timeout, with adal error of “Invalid_state”.
I made sure to Grant Permissions on Azure for the UI App to call the Web App.

Comment: I got it to work, but only after modifying the code in adal.js as per [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/698)  and in adal.service.js as per [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/690).

Comment: Do you use ng2-adal?

Comment: Yes, version 2.0.0